# How to reference current workbook filename/path in PowerQuery?

Tags: powerquery

Is there any sound way of getting full filename for the workbook where PowerQuery query resides inside from this query?

I tried to do this by inserting formula `=CELL("filename")` in a hidden worksheet, but this is not reliable. When I switch workbooks, this cell randomly changes value, and it doesn't [always] return it to original workbook filename after I switch back. Formula calculation is set to "Automatic".

That's why I 'm asking this question. Is there other method or workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using

```
=cell("filename",indirect("A1",TRUE))
```

Excel will evaluate the Cell() function based on last active cell if [Reference] is omitted.